gitlab cicd step that builds docker image continues even when a build step fails
I have a Gitlab CICD pipeline that builds a docker image using docker buildkit. As part of this build, one of my run steps is to install Python packages. I can see an error in this run step in the CICD pipeline, but it continues to finish building the image, and even succeeds in the pipeline step! However, when I build the same image locally, I get an error on this step and the image does not continue to build.
An example of what the execution output looks like in the CICD pipeline is below
1/5 ..... done
2/5 ..... done
3/5 ..... "Error"
4/5 ..... done
5/5 ..... done

Locally when I build I get this
1/5 ..... done
2/5 ..... done
3/5 ..... ERROR
Error: "My error": exit code: 1

Any idea of why this would continue running the pipeline in the Gitlab runner, but not locally? Runner version is 16.11.1

Show us the Dockerfile and the pipeline file
